# How to be notified when a USB device was plugged in?

Tags: linux, usb, devices, notifications

My system has to auto-mount USB devices; how can I be notified when a USB device is plugged in?  Where can I read more about this subject?

I would like to handle this problem via C or a shell script.

Comment: And what about specifically "user space" options? I want my own shell script to run A) when a drive becomes available (e.g. auto-mount) and B) when a drive is about to become unavailable (e.g. "unmount" via gvfs or a gui file manager.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Udev support running [external programs](http://reactivated.net/writing_udev_rules.html)

```
KERNEL=="sdb", RUN+="/usr/bin/my_program"
```

Comment: Tip: You can use https://github.com/mgorny/sw-notify-send for that external program.

Comment: @lkraav: FWIW, You should be able to *edit* this answer...

Comment: Don't udev RUN commands run as root? Is there a way to set up a script to run from an unprivileged user space? Thanks.