# Sync files from a mac to a flash drive - automatically?

Tags: ubuntu, backup, rsync, macintosh

I have a flash drive, let's name it `FLASH`.

I want, when on my mac, when `FLASH` is plugged (and automatically mounted), execute a specific script and make `~/Documents` to be automatically copied to `/Volumes/FLASH/Documents` (mac mounts drives at `/Volumes`).

This same drive, `FLASH`, (with this new `Documents` folder added before with the mac situation), when plugged in an Ubuntu machine, I want it to automatically copy `FLASH/Documents` to `~/Documents` (or automatically execute an script, after mounting).

How should I do this in these different scenarios? I don't want to use third party applications for this, I prefer using core/builtin tools available in both platforms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `launchd` item using the `StartOnMount` key!

```
# example launchd plist file using StartOnMount key
open -e /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.backupd-attach.plist
```

Further information:

- [The macosxhints Forums: launchD StartOnMount help](http://hintsforums.macworld.com/showthread.php?t=112342)
- [MacEnterprise: Snow Leopard, launchd, and Lunch](http://www.mactech.com/articles/mactech/Vol.25/25.10/2510MacEnterprise-SnowLeopard-launchdandLunch/index.html)

  (Recipe 7: Run a script when a volume is mounted)

Comment: This is great @jon. Welcome to StackExchange network. :)

Answer (score 1):

On the Mac, use [Do Something When](http://www.azarhi.com/Projects/DSW/), a free software which triggers actions when you mount/unmount a drive.

On the Linux side, [udev](http://reactivated.net/writing_udev_rules.html) can run an external program when a disk is inserted (see e.g. [How to be notified when a USB device was plugged in?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/6894/how-to-be-notified-when-a-usb-device-was-plugged)).

Comment: I've update my question, I don't want to use third party applications. Thanks for the answer though.